# Как работать с таким массивом?

Tags: javascript

```
var stations = [
    {x:389,y:670,name:'Красногвардейская',id:45},
    {x:389,y:654,name:'Домодедовская',id:29},
    {x:389,y:644,name:'Орехово',id:73},
    {x:389,y:634,name:'Царицыно',id:122},
    и тд
```

Как например вызвать x из первой строки?

Comment: @HappyCougar ну вы даёте

Answer (score 3):

как это обычно в массивах и объектах и делается:

```
var newX = stations[0].x
```